# Generate PDF from base64 String PHP

Tags: php, pdf, corrupt

I'm trying to create a .pdf file with a base64 string from an image, and I can create it correctly, but when I try to open the file, the program sends a message that tells the file is corrupt or something like that..

I got this code:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '../image/');
$img = $_POST['image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$uniqueNumber = uniqid();
$namefile = $uniqueNumber.'.png';
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . $namefile;
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
$namefile = $uniqueNumber.'.pdf';
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . $namefile;
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

I can open the .png file correctly so, i think it's not problem from the base64 decoded string. Thank you all!

EDIT:

I'm trying this code and getting the same issue.

```
$data = base64_decode ($img);
//Write data back to pdf file
$pdf = fopen ('test.pdf','w');
fwrite ($pdf,$data);
//close output file
fclose ($pdf);
echo 'Done';
```

Is that becouse i'm saving an image with .pdf ? I think no, because if i'm doing fopen with .pdf should be with that format.

EDIT 2:

FOUND A SOLUTION.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php

I followed these steps and i can get that, thank you all!

Comment: You just crate a "png" (image) file and named it with ".pdf" extension. That is NOT a pdf.

Comment: Tho make a pdf you need more "code" :) 
look at this post [how to create pdf with PHP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php

Comment: I'm trying to use these pdf solutions but I'll have to pay cause the number of PDF's created..

Answer (score 1):

Check out DOMPDF: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

You can definitely use DOMPDF to create a PDF with an image tag whose source is that Base64 string. and render that to PDF.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$img = $_POST['image'];
$html =
 '<html><body>'.
 '<img src="'.$img.
 '"></body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```